# Joining tables in sql for many to many relation

Tags: sql, join

```
create table matches (id int, team_a_id int, team_b_id int, winner_id int); <br>
create table teams (id, name )
```

Here are two tables and I want to join them in a way that `team_a_id`, `team_b_id` and `winner_id` is changed to name of the team and entire table remains same as a first table. I am unable to think how can i achieve it. Please can anyone help me out.

```
o/p <br>
id | first_team_name | second_team_name | winner_name |
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What is in Winner_id if its a draw???

Answer (score 2):

A simple JOIN can do that. You'll have to join `teams` once per name you want, if the match is guaranteed to have a winner, you can use a regular JOIN instead of the LEFT JOIN below which will show games even if there's no winner yet.

```
SELECT m.id, 
       t1.name first_team_name, 
       t2.name second_team_name, 
       t3.name winner_name
FROM matches m
JOIN teams t1 ON t1.id = team_a_id
JOIN teams t2 ON t2.id = team_b_id
LEFT JOIN teams t3 ON t3.id = winner_id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccd155/3).

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN`? Is it faster?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No, just to get a result for - for example - games that are planned but don't yet have a winner.

Comment: OK, but you can `LEFT JOIN` only ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming all games have been played and there can only be one winner

SELECT Matches.Id, tA.NAME  first_team_name, tB.Name second_team_name, tW.Name winner_name
FROM matches 
INNER JOIN teams tA ON TA.id = team_a_id
INNER JOIN teams tB ON TB.id = team_b_id
INNER JOIN teams tW ON TW.id = winner_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `JOIN` to the teams table each time:

```
SELECT m.id, 
    f.name first_team_name, 
    s.name second_team_name, 
    w.name winner_name
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN teams f ON m.team_a_id = f.id
INNER JOIN teams s ON m.team_b_id = s.id
INNER JOIN teams w ON m.winner_id = w.id
```